# Clarification needed on numpy array multiplication in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

How is `X.dot(X)` different from `X[0,:].dot(X[0,:])`, if `X = np.random.rand(1,2)`?

I realize `X.dot(X)` is throwing me an error and rightly so as I am multiplying (1,2) with (1,2). But then how is `X[0,:].dot(X[0,:])` different. I checked for the shape of `X[0,:]` it shows `(2,)`. I can't see how the multiplication succeeds with this shape.

Comment: shape of `x[0,:]` should be (2,) not (N,) check it again.

Comment: Yeah my bad. Edited it now.

Comment: `dot` docs explains what happens when an input is 1d. or both are 1d.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply dot product on matrix or array with more than one axis then there shape should be `nxm` and `mxn` respectively.
Since shape of `X` in your case is `1x2` so for dot product you have multiply it by `2x1`, which can be achieved by `X.T`(numpy transpose).

`X.dot(X.T)` gives `array([[0.8091749]])` as output.

`X[0,:].dot(X[0,:])` : this works because it is one dimensional vector and numpy automatically infer how to apply dot product on 1-D vector. You can do it manually too by using `X[0,:].dot(X[0,:].T)`.

Both should give the same result.

Comment: `X[0,:].T` is the same as `X[0,:]`.  `.T` does not change a 1d array, (2,) shape remains (2,).

Comment: @hpaulj Should I change anything in answer? I just included to make consistency in notation.

Comment: Perhaps a little context could help, I was trying to find the radius from a set of polar coordinates X =  [r* cost r*sint].

Comment: Elaborate your problem or you may include it in your question.